# Convert XML til JSON with Powershell

Tags: json, xml, powershell

This feels like a n00b question but I can't figure out how to solve it.

I have some XML in a file:

```
<EquipmentMessage>
    <Equipment>
        <UnitNo>AT_456578</UnitNo>
        <UnitRegNo>456578</UnitRegNo>
        <UnitRegNoCountry>AT</UnitRegNoCountry>
        <UnitOwner>000692</UnitOwner>
        <UnitOwnerID>6406601449</UnitOwnerID>
        <UnitOwnerTerms/>
        <UnitAdministrator>HAP</UnitAdministrator>
        <UnitAdministratorTerms/>
        <UnitManagement/>
        <UnitManagementTerms/>
        <UnitPoolID/>
        <MainCategory>TRUCK</MainCategory>
        <AssetType>HEAVYHigh</AssetType>
        <UnitCategory>HEAVY</UnitCategory>
        <UnitSize>High</UnitSize>
        <UnitType/>
        <UnitSubType>18 t</UnitSubType>
        <UnitRedeliverAct/>
        <SubContractorID>6406601449</SubContractorID>
    </Equipment>
</EquipmentMessage>
```

Which I want to convert into JSON and save in another file. So I read in the XML file and convert to JSON using:

```
[xml]$xmlfile = Get-Content .\Equipment.xml
$json = Convertto-json $xmlfile
```

But the JSON object contains:

```
[
    [
        [
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement",
            "System.Xml.XmlElement"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Am I reading in the XML wrong or am I missing something in the conversion or is it something else?

Comment: I would appear that the data structure here is too complicated to be simply converted to JSON. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636510/convert-multiple-xmls-to-json-list) that built a conversion function. I ran your xml through it and it was perfect `$xml | ConvertFrom-Xml | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5`